# i want to locate the file in visual studio code that is inside public folder

Tags: reactjs, pathname

i want to locate the pathname for the image that i want to use in the project but i can't find the image.
I have tried giving like this '../images/logo.png', but it shows  Module not found: Can't resolve './images/logo.png' in 'C:\Users\55590i5 D'\Desktop\react-website-v2-master\src\components'

the file i.e. logo.png to access is inside public->images->logo.png and i want to import it inside src->components->navbar.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going quite far up enough in the directory tree with that path. Starting from navbar.js, these would be the parts of the path:

1. ../ (up to /components)
2. ../ (up to src)
3. ../ (up to the project root)
4. public
5. images
6. logo.png

so the full relative path would be `../../../public/images/logo.png`.

However, if that's a create-react-app project, you can't import from public when you are inside src. Usually you would put an image you're trying to import somewhere under `src` (like in a `src/assets` folder, for example). See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files for more on this.